# Using ternary operator in build method

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class CategoryViewDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryViewDetail({Key? key, required bool tabbarenable})
      : super(key: key);
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[];

    return FutureBuilder<Categories>(
      future: _futureCategories,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final name = snapshot.data?.data;
          var filteredList = name
              ?.where((name) =>
                  name.name == 'Spor' ||
                  
              .toList();
//here I want to hide tabbar if the page comes with CategoryViewDetail(tabbarenable: false)
          for (int i = 0; i < filteredList!.length; i++) {
            tabs.add(
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  ' ${filteredList[i].name}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                      color: Colors.black54),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

I want to bypass tabbar if page comes with tabbareanble = false but in this way Build Widget does not recognise tabbarenable variable.

ayn help?

Comment: I'm not getting this line `name.name == 'Spor' || .toList();` is there any typing mistakes or maybe I'm not aware of it.

Comment: the correct is: `name.name == 'Spor'.toList();`the problem I can not get the value of tabbarenable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is a `StatefulWidget`, to access the parameter supplied to the widget in the `State`'s build method you'll need to access the parameter through the `State`'s widget property: `widget.tabbarenable`